# JAVA: dynamic object property of a class using a variable

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop

I'm learning OOP and java with an online-course. This chapter is about access modifiers and you have to call every possible attribute of TestRobot.

Now I've tried it with an array of the attributes and wanted to use a for-loop to check them all if they exist. Of course, I could just do it 4 times but this is redundant somehow. :D Now I have an error that there is no symbol attributes. My suggestion is that the compiler is checking in the class robots for "attributes".

Is there a possibility to tell java that attributes is an array or variable of the class Terminal instead part of the class robot itself? For example in JavaScript you would just write `robots[attributes[i]]`.

Is it even possible to call EVERY attribute of a class?

```
class TestRobot {
    private int secretKey = 602413;
    protected int numberOfProcessorCores = 4;
    boolean hasFirewall = false;
    public String id = "58-08-2";
}


class Terminal {
    String[] attributes = {"secretKey", "numberOfProcessorCores", "hasFirewall", "id"};
    
    public void hackRobot(TestRobot robot) {
        for(int i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++){
            if(robot.attributes[i]) {
                System.out.println(attributes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically you can do this using java Reflection to get the fields of a class but that's quite an advanced technique if you're only just learning about access modifiers.

Comment: The JavaScript example you give seems to be for iterating *HTML* Attributes, not JavaScript / object attributes

Comment: @DLynch Thank you. I just completed the task with the "old" fashioned way. :D Maybe I will use java Reflection API later. Was just wodnering, because in other languages it seems to be so easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible through *reflection API*. You can get a list of attributes dynamically with `TestRobot.class.getDeclaredAttributes()`, then you can programmatically inspect the type of each field, its visibility, and you can get/set the values of those attributes on an instance of `TestRobot`.